# Подводные камни использования Optional<T> вместе с @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, optional

Так как не все параметры HTTP запроса могут быть обязательными, часто приходится делать проверки на null перед их использованием. Из-за чего возникла идея использовать Optional прямо в сигнатуре контроллера и передавать его запакованным в слой бизнес-логики. Примерно так:

```
@Controller
void bar(@RequestParam (required = false) Optional<String> foo) {
   someServise.do(foo);
   ...
}
```

Насколько это удачное решение, и какие возможны подводные камни? Idea, например, сразу подчеркнула, что возможны проблемы с сериализацией.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым главным предназначением **Optional<T>** является возможность указать что результат при вызове метода может отсутствовать. Попытка применить его в других целях, в особенности в качестве параметра метода или в качестве поля объекта противоречит основной указанной идее.

У **Optional<T>** много функции, и наверняка вы захотите использовать только одну из его особенностей. К примеру в вашем случае:

- если при отсутствии значении подразумевается его замена на другое,
  пожалуй, более элегантным способом будет использование `defaultValue
  = "other value"` вместо `required = false`
- если при отсутствии значении надо выбросить исключение, то можно оставить `required
  = true`(по умолчанию)
- если нужно выполнить определенное действие только если значение не
  пустое, то так уж и быть, проверка на null в каком то ключе может окажется более наглядным